# How do I import QGIS C++ libraries into my Qt/C++ project?

Tags: qgis, c++, qt

I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04 and I downloaded QGIS Desktop version 2.18.14...

I also have Qt Creator version 3.0.1 (based on Qt 5.2.1)...

When I downloaded QGIS Desktop via the Ubuntu software center, shared libraries such as libqgis-core2.0.1 were also downloaded....

I can't seem to find the paths to these libraries....

How can I import/include these libraries for a C++ project in Qt Creator or is there some other way to use the QGIS C++ API?